# Probabilistic linear regression

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-integral

Suppose
$$x=Pt+e$$
$$y=Ct+f$$
where $t\sim N(0,I)$, $e\sim N(0,\Sigma_x)$, and $f\sim N(0,\Sigma_y)$. Also, $\Sigma_x\in R^{d\times d}$, $\Sigma_y\in R^{k\times k}$, and $t\in R^r$ One can compute the marginal probability density function of $(x,y)$ as following
$$p(x,y)=\int p(x,y,t)dt=\int N(Pt,\Sigma_x)N(Ct,\Sigma_y)N(0,I)dt$$
Expanding out and rearranging the terms in the exponents, the above equation becomes the following
$$\dfrac{1}{2\pi^{(d+k+r)/2}|\Sigma_x|^{1/2}|\Sigma_y|^{1/2}}\int \exp(x^T\Sigma_x^{-1}x+y^T\Sigma_y^{-1}y-2(x^T\Sigma_x^{-1}P^T+y^T\Sigma_y^{-1}C^T)t+t^T(P^T\Sigma_x^{-1}P+C^T\Sigma_y^{-1}C+I)t)dt$$
I realize that the complex term in the exponent of the above equation is a quadratic form of $t$ which might be rearranged into the form $(t-\mu_t)^T\Sigma_t^{-1}(t-\mu_t)$. I managed to obtain $\Sigma_t=(P^T\Sigma_x^{-1}P+C^T\Sigma_y^{-1}C+I)^{-1}$. Is it therefore correct to simplify the integral as the following by using the property of the multivariate Gaussian distribution?
$$\int \exp(x^T\Sigma_x^{-1}x+y^T\Sigma_y^{-1}y-2(x^T\Sigma_x^{-1}P^T+y^T\Sigma_y^{-1}C^T)t+t^T(P^T\Sigma_x^{-1}P+C^T\Sigma_y^{-1}C+I)t)dt=2\pi^{r/2}|P^T\Sigma_x^{-1}P+C^T\Sigma_y^{-1}C+I|^{1/2}$$

If it is correct, the marginal $p(x,y)$ becomes irrelevant of $(x,y)$ which is weird.Can anyone point out where I might got it wrong?

Comment: I personally cannot help you with this, and I think this question is worthy of more attention. Maybe you can rephrase parts of it or edit it with some format highlighting your troubles. If in the end it is completely overlooked, you can go ask this on the statistics site http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Lee, I have identified the problem of the above derivation. This was all due to a fundamental mistake which i will explain in detail in the edit.

Comment: Good to know. In that case, I suggest you post it as an answer and check it to "accept" it (once you have reputation of 15+). That way this question will not be listed as "unanswered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update and Correction**
$$$$
I have now identified the problem with the above derivation, which was all due to a fundamental mistake as explained below. I have assumed, due to $p(x,y,t)\propto p(t|x,y)$
$$p(x,y)=\int p(x,y,t)dt=\int p(t|x,y)dt$$
which is absurdly wrong. The correct way of doing it is through partitioning.
$$P(x,y,t)=\begin{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x^T\\y^T\end{bmatrix}\\t^T\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_x^{-1}&0\\0&\Sigma_y^{-1}\end{bmatrix}&\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_x^{-1}P^T\\\Sigma_y^{-1}C^T\end{bmatrix}\\\begin{bmatrix}P\Sigma_x^{-1}&C\Sigma_y^{-1}\end{bmatrix}&P^T\Sigma_x^{-1}P+C^T\Sigma_y^{-1}C\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\\t\end{bmatrix}$$

One can easily compute $Var[x,y]$ by applying the matrix inversion lemma on the square block matrix in the middle of the above expression. It is also easy to see that $E(x,y)=0$.